# Why does my folder remain there even after i delete?

Tags: windows-10

I am using Windows 10 pro. Sometimes when i delete or move a folder, the contents are moved but an empty folder remains in the source directory. When I try to access it, windows throws an error message as "Access is denied".
Only after restart, I can delete that empty folder. It happens to me very often. Can someone tell me what's the root cause of the problem? And how to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 - High level OS folder, taken ownership but still can't modify](http://superuser.com/questions/1059873/windows-10-high-level-os-folder-taken-ownership-but-still-cant-modify)

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered here: [Windows 10 - High level OS folder, taken ownership but still can't modify](https://superuser.com/questions/1059873/windows-10-high-level-os-folder-taken-ownership-but-still-cant-modify)

This is usually related to the folder / file ownership. Go to the object properties and check the security settings, you should try to get ownership first and then delete the folder.

Another reason might be because the folder is still in use by other process (e.g. your mail application etc may use few files from there and it is still open and references to this file). I could see this frequently at my desk.

Comment: Typically when an [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/1059873/windows-10-high-level-os-folder-taken-ownership-but-still-cant-modify/1060770#1060770) to another [question](http://superuser.com/questions/1059873/windows-10-high-level-os-folder-taken-ownership-but-still-cant-modify), answers a question like this, one should flag a question like this as a duplicate of that other question.

Comment: Still the issue is not resolved. I am sure that no other operation is performed in that folder by me. Actually its just a downloads folder in D drive. I wont open any files in that. I will move all the downloads once it is finished. So there is no poosibility of other applications that have opened it. Even though the contents are moved, the empty folder remains there and throws some error.